# How to write a While Loop for Simple Increments?

Tags: java, while-loop

I will need to write a WHILE loop for the following: "hello" is part of the output

8 9 11 14 hello 18

```
    while(counter < 18 )
    {
        System.out.print(" " + counter);

        counter = counter + 1 ;

        if(counter > 14 && counter < 18){
            System.out.print(" hello ");
        }

    }
```

The above is my sample code. I am unable to figure out how to increase it by 1, 2 then 3. Can anyone help , please?

Comment: I am guessing this is homework. If so, please tag it as such. I have left my answer vague, because if it is homework, I don't want to spoil your epiphany :)

Answer (score 4):

You need an additional variable that stores the amount by which you increment. This variable itself has to be incremented by one in each run of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
        int counter = 8;
        int inc = 1;
        while ( counter <= 18 )
        {
            System.out.print ( " " + counter );
            if ( counter >= 14 && counter < 18 )
            {
                System.out.print ( " hello " );
            }
            counter = counter + inc;

            inc += 1;
        }
```